# find, excluding dir, not descending into dir, AND using maxdepth and mindepth

Tags: unix, sh

This is RHEL 5.6 and GNU find 4.2.27.

I am trying to exclude a directory from find, and want to make sure that directory isn't descended into.  I've seen plenty of posts saying -prune will do this - and it does.  I can run this command:

`find . -type d -name "./.snapshot*" -prune -o -print`

and it works.  I run it through strace and verify it is NOT descending into .snapshot.

I also want to find directories ONLY at a certain level.  I can use mindepth and maxdepth to do this:

`find . -maxdepth 8 -mindepth 8 -type d`

and it gives me all the dirs 8 levels down, including what's in .snapshot.

If I combine the prune and mindepth and maxdepth options:

`find . -maxdepth 8 -mindepth 8 -type d \( -path "./.snapshot/*" -prune  -o -print \)`

the output is right - I see all the dirs 8 levels down except for what's in .snapshot, but if I run that find through strace, I see that .snapshot is still being descended into - to levels 1 through 8.

I've tried a variety of different combinations, moving the precedence parens around, reording expression components - everything that yields the right output still descends into .snapshot.

I see in the man page that -prune doesn't work with -depth, but doesn't say anything about mindepth and maxdepth.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks...
Bill

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your answer. -mindepth seems to turn off all test till that level. kind of a bummer.

(right from "man find")

```
   -mindepth levels
          **Do not apply any** tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative integer).
          '-mindepth 1' means process all  files  except  the  command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as another answer because it's a different take on the issue. You could try the find command like this :

find * .[^s][^n]* (other switches/args)

It would avoid the .snapshot directory by using the shell instead of the find switches. granted it's not perfect but maybe it's close enough for what you are doing.